# Can't multi-select with shift key on Fedora 21

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, gnome-shell

On Fedora 21 when I do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> with text or anything else, the selection doesn't work. Instead the "dragging hand" cursor appears and I can move window with a mouse.

The window sticks to the screen edges while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

How to turn off such behavior and make it possible to select text?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and with the help of the Gnome team found [a process to get things working](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=744122) again.  In short, just remove your `~/.config` directory which will reset all of your settings, but does fix the issue.